# Renamed Wordpress-Heroku app admin pages redirect to old name

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, heroku

Using [Wordpress-Heroku](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku) and ran into some issues. Changed my app name from heroku's autogenerated name to something more descriptive, but /wp-admin gets redirected to the old name. Of course there's no such app anymore. Also tried to set up a local version but found that going to localhost:8888/wp-admin redirects me to app on heroku.

I guess that something in the installation process creates permalinks to the site address in the database. Is there a way to fix this without resetting the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change servers (copying live sites to localhost) fairly frequently following [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change).  While not on Heroku, I assume the process would be the same.

In your case, the [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) mentioned should do the trick (after backing up the database, of course).

I assume you've updated your `wp-config.php` to point to the new database.

Comment: Thanks. Never worked with wordpress before so it's weird to me that the links aren't just all relative.

Comment: No worries.  Yeah, it's a pain.  Not made easier by the fact they can be stored PHP-serialised, meaning you can't just do a SQL update to change them.

Comment: For anyone else coming here with the same issue: the script failed to run on Heroku, probably because it ran for more than 30 seconds and timed out (like any process would on free tier). Might work locally and then you push the database, but I won't be trying it out.  I'm going to host on EC2 instead, where I can run updates and install plugins online.